# Cannot click button on bot controlled browser

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, graphql, puppeteer

I try to accept cookies on twitch.tv site on automation started browser, but I cannot.

```bash
pip install selenium
python3
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get("https://twitch.tv")
And to be sure I'm manually clicking Accept Cookies button
```

Instead of closing cookie consent bar I've got:
`[GraphQL] One or more GraphQL errors were detected on request (...). UpdateConsentMutation: failed integrity check`

This problem occurs on both puppeteer and selenium on both firefox and chromium. Both firefox and chromium when started normally are able to accept cookies.

How to debug/fix that?